# Problems with nested list indexes

Tags: python

```
meteo = open('meteo.txt', 'r+')
meteo.seek(0, 0) # cursor at the beginnig of the file
ar = [] # list of list
a=True # boolean to control the loop
x=0 # index
while a:
    com=[meteo.readline(), meteo.readline(), meteo.readline()]
    ar.append(com) # appending a list with data from meteo.txt
    com.clear() # clearing com to hold next reading
    if ar[x][0] == '': # checking if the last reading was a list of string to terminate the loop otherwise
        a=False
    x=x+1
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\DEV - enviroment\Python\Script\Es. 56 Pag. 157.py", line 11, in <module>
    if ar[x][0] == '':
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I think that the error is in the number of elements of the list, but I couldn't fix it.

[Edit]
I've been asked to add the format of meteo.txt and essentially it is formatted like this:

```
city1
dd/mm/yyyy
celsius_temperature1
city2
dd/mm/yyyy
celsius_temperature2
...
```

Here an example of meteo.txt:

```
Castelfranco Emilia
20/04/2018
20
Modena
20/04/2018
23
Piumazzo
20/04/2018
19
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the contents of `meteo.txt`?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `ar[x]`, is a list of strings

Comment: Why are you `clear`ing `com` before you try to access its elements?

Comment: as @user2357112 mentions, your `ar` simply stores a reference to `com`, and so when you `clear` it, it is no longer a list of strings, but an empty reference. Considering clearing it afterwards.

Comment: @Riccardo: a hint for future debugging: put the `print` statement *immediately* before the use.  In this case, you didn't see the error because you printed your variables, but then `clear`ed `com` before the failure point.

Comment: Thank you @Prune

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because shallow copying of the lists or in better terms; referencing instead of copying the values at memory. If you want to use clear function you need to deep copy the com list. Here is what you do at the moment:

```
>>> li = []
>>> inli = [1, 2, 3]
>>> li.append(inli)
>>> li
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>> inli
[1, 2, 3]
>>> inli.clear()
>>> li
[[]]
>>> inli
[]
```

And what you need to do is:

```
>>> import copy
>>> li = []
>>> inli = [1, 2, 3]
>>> li.append(copy.deepcopy(inli))
>>> li
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>> inli
[1, 2, 3]
>>> inli.clear()
>>> li
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>> inli
[]
```

Or better just don't use clear function at all:

```
>>> li = []
>>> inli = [1, 2, 3]
>>> li.append(inli)
>>> li
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>> inli
[1, 2, 3]
>>> inli = [4, 5, 6]
>>> li
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>> inli
[4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic is that you read three lines into a list `com`, append the list *in toto* to `ar`, and then clear the sub-list.  `ar` holds a reference to `com`, rather than its own copy of the three strings you read.

When you clear `com`, your reference from `ar` is also cleared; `ar[x]` is now an empty list, with no element 0.

You need to copy the elements; use `deepcopy`, or perhaps re-factor your logic to perform the needed operations; your posted code is unnecessarily complicated for what this snippet tries to do.  For instance, `com` doesn't really do much toward getting lines into `ar` and detecting an empty line.